# Redux store Array to Div list of elements

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a list of object stored as a array in my redux store which loads on component mount. I want to List them in a div, also to do the crud Operation. This is my implementation. Whenever I use useSelector to save the list for a constants it fectching infinite number of logs.

**BranchAction.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchAllBranchListOk = (branchList) => {
    return {
        type : 'FETCH_ALL_BRANCH_LIST_OK',
        branchList
    }
};

export const fetchAllBranchList = () =>{
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(fetchAllBranchListOk(response.data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            });
    }
};
```

**BranchReducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ALL_BRANCH_LIST_OK' :
            return action.branchList;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**BranchManagement.js**

```
function BranchManagement() {
    store.dispatch(BranchAction.fetchAllBranchList());
    const AllBranch = useSelector(state => state.BranchReducer)
    return(
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default BranchManagement;
```

**CombinedReducer -> index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import BranchReducer from "./Admin/BranchReducer";

const Reducers = combineReducers({
   BranchReducer
});

export default Reducers;
```

Comment: Will you please provide `combine reducer` code also?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have added

Comment: Instead of doing `const AllBranch = useSelector(state => state.BranchReducer)` you can do `const AllBranch = useSelector(state => state.branchList)`. And I do not understand why you are calling `store.dispatch(BranchAction.fetchAllBranchList());` inside the component directly?

Comment: @NithishGandesiri I need to load the list of array to the store, thats the reason i called store.dispatch directly referring to a tutorial. as am beginer for react

Comment: Ideally you should be doing that in `useEffect` since you are using `hooks`. Here what'll happen is when you load the component, trying to update the state(in store) and when the state gets updated the component will re-render and again it'll try to update data. So it'll be an infinite loop.

Comment: @NithishGandesiri, yeah thats the issue am facing on. Sorry couldn't mention in the question. How should I implement the useEffect in the above code of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `dispatch` the action to fetch the data from the backed, you should be keeping those calls in `useEffect` hook. The purpose of useEffect is similar to the purpose of Lifecycle methods in the class component like `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnMount`. To understand more about `useEffect` please refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import BranchAction from "/path/to/BranchAction";

function BranchManagement() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    //Since the data in the state is on `branchList`. You can directly return 
    //`state.branchList` which will you provide you the data you are looking for.
    const branchList = useSelector(state => state.branchList)

    //It'll act similar to `componentDidMount`. Since we are passing `[]` 
    //to `useEffect` dependencies array
    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(BranchAction.fetchAllBranchList());
    }, [])

    //Here I'm assuming `branchList` is array of objects with `name` and `id`. 
   //Updated answer with branchList as[{"branchID":1,"createdBy":1,"isActive":true,"branchDetails":{"branchDetailsID":1}},{"branchID":2,"createdBy":1,"isActive":true,"branchDetails":{"branchDetailsID":1}}]
    return(
        <div>
          {
           (branchList || []).map((branch, index) => {
                 <div key={branch.branchID || index}>
                     <span>{branch.branchID}</span>
                     <span>{branch.createdBy}</span>
                     <span>{branch.isActive}</span>
                     <span>{branch.branchDetails.branchDetailsID}</span>
                 </div>
           }
          }
        </div>
    )
}
export default BranchManagement;
```

Hope this helps in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: I used the above, Am able to fetch the array, but I am unable map it to a div. 
AllBranchList: [
    {
      branchID: 1,
      createdBy: 1,
      isActive: true,
      branchDetails: {
        branchDetailsID: 1,
      }
    },
{
      branchID: 2,
      createdBy: 1,
      isActive: true,
      branchDetails: {
        branchDetailsID: 1,
      }
    }
  ]

this is my array value. could you help on this please

Comment: What are the details that you want to display from the list?

Comment: branchID, CreatedBy, branchDetailsID, BranchAddress. Branch address is defined inside the branch details object.

Comment: Updated the answer by considering the provided json object. Please check